# JavaScript's document.cookie does not replace cookie in the subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies, replace, subdomain

I'm having trouble setting cookies.


When I call `document.cookies = "cookieName=cookieValue;path=/;domain=domain.com";` from a subdomain like "subdomain.domain.com", Chrome shows the cookie being set on both, the domain and the subdomain I'm in. This is not ideal, since I only want to set it on the domain, but for now it's fine with me.


The problem is when I want to replace the cookie. If I call the same line but with a different cookie value like `document.cookies = "cookieName=cookieValue2;path=/;domain=domain.com";`, Chrome shows the cookie getting replaced in the domain, but not the subdomain. This is a problem.


Can someone help me with this?

Comment: > Chrome shows the cookie getting replaced in the domain, but not the subdomain. -- This does not make sense. Can you double check?

Comment: @Halcyon Yep, I'm looking at it through the developer console. I put a break point before the JavaScript line, when it hits, I look at the cookies on the resources tab, I step over the line, look back at the resources tab and there's indeed one cookie changed and not the other.

Comment: @Halcyon FYI, I'm using Google Translate's page translation plugin that translates your page into a language you tell it to by putting a cookie named "googletrans"; if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure what's happening with this, but the work around I found was to simply set the cookie twice: one without specifying the `domain` (which replaces the subdomain cookie) and one for the domain:

```
document.cookies = "cookieName=cookieValue;path=/"; //Replaces the subdomain cookie
document.cookies = "cookieName=cookieValue;path=/;domain=domain.com"; //Replaces the domain cookie
```